# Why convolution obtained from matlab differs from what is obtained theoretically?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, convolution

Theoretical result for convolution of an exponential function with a sinusoidal function is shown below.

[image]

When I plot the function directly using matlab, I get this,
[image: Direct plot of the analytical result]

However Matlab conv command yields this,
[image: Plot obtained from Matlab]

The two plots look similar but they are not the same, see the scales. The matlab yield is ten times of the theoretical result. Why?

The matlab code is here.

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;
t = 0:0.1:50;
x1 = exp(-t);
x2 = sin(t);
x = conv(x1,x2);
x_theory = 0.5.*(exp(-t) + sin(t) - cos(t));

figure(1)
subplot(313), plot(t, x(1:length(t))); subplot(311), plot(t, x1(1:length(t))); subplot(312), plot(t, x2(1:length(t)))

figure(2)
subplot(313), plot(t, x_theory); subplot(311), plot(t, x1(1:length(t))); subplot(312), plot(t, x2(1:length(t)))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`conv` does *discrete-time* convolution, it does not do the mathematical integral function. Numerically, this basically means multiplying and adding the result of the two signals many times, once for each point, with a small shift of one of the signals.

If you think about this, you will realize that the sampling of the signals will have an effect. i.e. if you have a point every 0.1 values, or 0.001 values, the amount of points you multiply is different, and thus the result is different in value (not in shape).

Therefore, every time you do numerical convolution, you always need to multiply with the sampling rate, to "normalize" the operation.

Just change your code to do

```
sampling_rate= 0.1;
t = 0:sampling_rate:50;
x = conv(x1,x2)*sampling_rate;
```

Comment: @ Ander Thank you. it helped, now they share the same scale, but I can still see asmall difference between the plots. Analytical result is little less than the matlab result.

Comment: @Vikash change the sample rate. Try 0.5. Now try 0.01. A numerical solution will always just be an approximations to the analytical one. This is true for all numerical approximations, not just convolution. (luckily this is why mathematicians still have a job :D)

Comment: I just increased the sampling rate to 0.001. Now the both results match well. Great! But how do I find the right sampling rate? If I am working on a research problem, and I do not have an analytical result to compare with, how do I decide on what value of sampling rate is appropriate?

Comment: @Vikash the right sampling rate is "0", i.e. infinite sampling points. Obviously this is impossible.  Anything larger will always have some error. This is why analytical solution for problems are generally desired.

Comment: @Vikash: Your sine function can be properly sampled with only just over two samples per period. But the exponential function cannot be sampled, you always make an error. Fourier analysis shows you how much of the power of the signal gets lost to aliasing. This allows you to pick a sampling rate where the loss of power is acceptable in your application.